# Overriding track.phtml in Magento2

Tags: magento2, template-override

I saw many such questions, but all answers are basically copies of the same solution with custom theme.
Is it possible just to override core file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml

without creating a custom theme? If so, what exactly path should I create to put altered track.phtml to?
My intention is to make collection of altered files that will not be overwritten during Magento or 3rd party theme automatic upgrade so I can easily keep all core functionality changes. And this will allows me to keep changes even if theme is switched to another one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override that file using different ways :

**1. Override template and xml file in your custom module :**

- You can add this XML file in your custom module and you can change path like..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml

Content for this file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.email.shipment.track">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::email/shipment/track.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

- After adding above xml file you need to create template file in your custom module here.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml

**2. Override template file in your custom theme :**

- You can copy **track.phtml** file here in your custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml

- After that you can change anything here based on your requirement.

**Note : In all above cases, your file will not change when you update your Magento version.**

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is above solution works for you ?

Comment: Hi Kishan. Thank you for the reply, but this way of adding new files to point to altered files seems to be not much useful for me.
So, there is no easy way of just copying original phtml file to correct place where Magento2 looks for overrides?

Comment: Can you please give me more information related to your query ? @Frenger

Comment: What exactly info do you need? Once again: I want to override core magento2 file located on the path specified in the question. I though it is possible just to copy that phtml to a path like app/design/frontend/ ... , but I don't know what are deeper levels of folders that I need to create to let Magento2 find this altered track.phtml file to use it instead of default one.

Comment: P.S. I don't have a custom module. I just want to add non-standard links to tracking numbers in the shipment confirmation emails. I did this editing core track.phtml file, but I need to edit it again after each Magento upgrade since it reverts to default code.

Comment: Custom module means you can create new module with these files.

- registration.php
- etc/module.xml
- view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml
- view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml

After creating this module, you do not need to change **track.phtml** file everytime when you upgrade your Magento version.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But nothing works in my setup except of direct core file editing. Ok. Will live with this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I made even a custom theme, and put altered track.phtm there. Changed theme, cleared cache, depoloyed static content etc. But Magento still using core file. May be something is screwed in my Magento setup. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hi @Frenger, can you please send me path where you've added **track.phtml** file in your custom theme ? Because I'm using same thing in my projects and that is working correctly without any issues.

Comment: Sorry, @Frenger I just checked I've added wrong path in second option. You can override that file here **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml**. Now this will definitely works for you.

Comment: I've updated path in answer as well you can check that and update that file there in your custom theme.

Comment: It is a magic! With this path it work now! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome Buddy!! You can give me an upvote. :) Happy to Help you.